# Get default validation input email on old browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to build a simple contact form for the newsletter subscription, the CF has just one input field (email) and the submit button. I used type="email" of HTML5 to check the the email and on the new browsers I get the default validation message:

[image]

This doesn't happen when I use older browsers obviously so I used the JS alert in case the user is using the old browsers, but this is not what I'd like.

I would like to get the same message (browser default) on all the browsers.

Here my code:

HTML

```
<div class="newsletter-wrap-flex margin-top-div">
  <div class="newsletter-title">
    <span>
      NEWSLETTER
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="newsletter-form">
    <form id="newsletter-cf" method="post" action="">
      <input id="contact-email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required/>
      <input id="contact-send" class="submit" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    </form>
    <div id="message-sent">Congratulation! Your request has been sent.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function checkEmail(inputvalue) {
 var pattern = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
 return pattern.test(inputvalue);
}


    $('#newsletter-cf').submit(function () {
      var email = document.getElementById("contact-email").value;
      if (!checkEmail(email))
     {
     alert('Email address is invalid');
     return false;
     }   
      $("#newsletter-cf").slideUp("slow");
      $("#message-sent").slideDown("slow");  
      return false;
    });
```

I've read there could be some ways like Modernizr but I've never used them before so I don't really know how to start.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "Old browsers" mean? You should specify :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant browsers that not support HTML5 like Safari9 or Safari9 mobile

Comment: Modernizr only checks to see what browser can support, then you can use third-party software to fill in the missing features. http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/